# Can you do an AND on Google Scholar alerts?

Tags: literature-search, google-scholar

In Google Scholar, you can create an alert, such as "neural networks", which will inform you any time there is an article related to "neural networks". However, suppose I am interested in neural networks applied to robot navigation. Is there a way to create an alert that will only inform you when both "neural networks" and "robot navigation" appear in the paper? Essentially, I want to do a logical AND on the search terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, all of the typical operators apply.

`AND` is implicit so your alert query could be `"neural networks" "robot navigation"`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alert for `neural networks + robotics` this way google will search all the results that have both words, and again if you are more interested in the robotics part you use a quotation mark like `neural networks + "robotics"` which brings all the results that absolutely have robotics in them.