# Google scholar doesn't send me citation alerts

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Google Scholar **fails to send me citation alerts or alerts when articles have been auto-included in my profile**. This happened about a year ago; before that, Scholar faithfully sent me the updates. In the meantime I have published articles (that were automatically added to my profile) and I've had quite some citations (despite, or thanks to Corona).

I did some troubleshooting:

- I have checked my email filters in [Google Workspace](https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#settings/filters) to see whether the Google Scholar email address (**Google Scholar Alerts** scholaralerts-noreply@google.com) was accidentally blocked from sending emails to my inbox, but it wasn't.
- I also cancelled all my alerts and requested them anew. All to no avail.
- Searching Google and the Stack Exchange network didn't yield any useful information, and I am suspecting a problem on my end.
- Emails are not drooped in my spam inbox, or any other place they shouldn't be.

Getting help from Google requires a paid account and that would be my last resort. I was hoping anyone here could help out.

<sub>I am unsure whether this is the right place to start, but I found the [google-scholar](/questions/tagged/google-scholar) tag and multiple questions posted on this forum about Scholar (*e.g.*, [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77614/creating-compound-alerts-with-google-scholar), [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94566/how-to-deliver-google-scholar-alerts-at-specific-time) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64870/can-you-do-an-and-on-google-scholar-alerts)).</sub>

Comment: Did you try emailing them: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/171200/19607

Comment: @Kimball - many thanks for the email address!! I couldn't find any support email anywhere! I've send them an email right away! Gracias.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are "following" your own profile, right?

Comment: @GoodDeeds - well, yes and no. When one creates a citation alert there's some process behind the screens and it's simply listed as 'citation alert'. I also created an alert manually with my surname+initials, but that I did only just yesterday, so I am awaiting activity. A new paper just came out today, so I am hoping that something will be triggered and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think you need to manually create an alert like that: just click the blue "Follow" button to the right of your profile picture. You can then ask to be alerted of all citations to papers in your profile. (unless I misunderstood your comment).

Comment: @GoodDeeds - I clicked that as well, thanks, but also only recently. Perhaps something will happen.

Comment: In the meantime I have had several citations to my works but no alerts came in. I really don't understand

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue about being alerted to new articles:

There is a setting where you can change whether you want Google Scholar to automatically update your profile with new articles it finds or to ask you to approve them. This might give you the alert that you are looking for that a new publication has been added.

To check/change this setting:

- Go to Google Scholar
- Click on "My Profile"
- In the gray bar above your list of publications, click the "+" to add articles and a dropdown menu will appear
- Select "Configure article updates"
- Select "Don't automatically update my profile. Send me email to review and confirm updates.

Comment: This response relates to new articles being added to one's profile. The OP is asking about citations to one's articles. This is an answer to a different problem.

Comment: They asked both about citations and new articles. I’ll edit my answer since I accidentally said new citations instead of new answers.